# ModalView only inside SubViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios5, modalviewcontroller, subview

I have this situation:

```
 ----------------------------
|  UIViewController          |
|                            |
|    --------------------    |
|   |                    |   |
|   |  SubViewController |   |
|   |                    |   |
|    --------------------    |
 ----------------------------
```

my SubViewController have a Tap Gesture:

```
- (void) tapped: (UIGestureRecognizer*) g 
{
    int tag=g.view.tag;
    UIViewController* vc = [controlersOfBoxes objectAtIndex:tag-1];

    UIViewController *controller = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [controller setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [controller.view setFrame:vc.view.frame];

    [vc presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is the dimensions of new UIViewController....i put the same frame that before view but... fill all screen...

I want that only change the SubViewController.

Any solution!!!

Answer (score 1):

If i get your problem , you want your view controller to occupy only assigned frame over parentviewcontroller.In that case , you cannot use PresentModalViewController..You have to use:-
alloc your second viewController(child)
assign frame:-

```
 yourSecondViewController.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
[self.view addSubView:yourSeconViewController.view];
```

Comment: My problem is that i want only modalview animation in a subviewcontroller not move all screen... is possible???

Comment: Use UIView Animation to get that